# Random effects in a linear model using BayesFactor package: why do bayes factors vary?

Tags: r, mixed-model, bayes-factors

I'm using the BayesFactor package with the lmBF and generalTestBF functions to compare different linear models that include participant as a random effect. Below is an example of one of these model comparisons:

```
Null.model.random = lmBF(RatioScore ~ Ppt, data = MockData, whichRandom = "Ppt")

C1.model = lmBF(RatioScore ~ C1 + Ppt, data = MockData, whichRandom = "Ppt")

C1.random = C1.model / Null.model.random
```

With each computation however, I get different Bayes Factors:

```
Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] C1 + Ppt : 1.599679 ±1.03%

Against denominator:
  RatioScore ~ Ppt 

Bayes factor analysis
--------------
[1] C1 + Ppt : 1.586607 ±1.01%

Against denominator:
  RatioScore ~ Ppt
```

I'm not sure why this is, although I think (from previous answers) it's due to Monte Carlo sampling, but why is this only the case when I include a random variable?

The main aim of these comparisons is to determine which is the best (i.e. most likely) model for our data, but if we get different BFs each time this leads to problems with interpretation, e.g. if two models have very similar BFs. Is there any way round this, for example a way to calculate the BFs without sampling? (I should also mention we are sometimes comparing many different models using the generalTestBF function, so testing specific models for each comparison isn't a straightforward option.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you set a random seed prior to your computation and then repeat the computation with the same random seed, will the result be the same? For example, try using set.seed(137) in front of your Null.model.random and set.seed(531) in front of your C1.model and see what happens. Each time you repeat, set the random seeds to these two (arbitrary) values and check whether the Bayes Factors remain the same.

Comment: Thanks Isabella! Using set.seed does stabilise the BFs. Do you know however if this has any theoretical implications - for example by selecting a particular seed am I biasing my results in any way?

Comment: The purpose of setting the seed is to make your results reproducible.  You can check the stability of your results by trying out a few choices of seeds.  In principle, the results should be fairly stable if the models are correctly specified.  If the results are not stable, then you would have little confidence in any specific findings you would report for a particular choice of seed.

Comment: Unfortunately the BFs are not very stable using different seeds, so we wouldn't have much confidence in the results even if they were reproducible. But thank you anyway for the helpful suggestion!

Comment: Maybe fit your models in a frequentist setting and look at diagnostic plots to see which model assumptions are not supported by your data? For example, your outcome variable may have a highly skewed distribution so it could benefit from a log-transformation? It's hard to offer more concrete advice without knowing more about your study.

Comment: My question isn't so much about how best to analyse our data, but more about why calculating BFs using the BayesFactor package are unstable when a random effect is included - this must be something to do with how they are calculated, as the same issue also occurs with a different dataset. We specifically want to compare multiple models using BFs, and the BayesFactor package would be ideal, but if we can't rely on the results from it I was wondering if there is an alternative.

Comment: My last comment was motivated by my not knowing anything about your study design and data to comment cogently on your particular situation.  The only advice I can give in the absence of this knowledge is that you should simulate some data where you know the truth (i.e., the correct model) and then see how the BayesFactor package deals with that. If it produces unstable BFs, then there is likely an issue with the package.

Comment: In your case, the issues of "am I using the correct model" versus "is the Bayes Factor doing strange things if the model is correct" are currently confounded - you need to establish first that your model's underlying assumptions are supported by the data and then you can proceed from there.